# .change() conflict?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have 2 changes, the live change works fine however the 2nd change for the selects does not seem to work, anyone got any idea or can these be merged together?

```
$(".shipping").live('change', function () {
    var billingId = $(this).attr('id').replace('_shipping_', '_billing_');
    $('#' + billingId).val($(this).val());
});

$("#same_shipping_address_title").change(function () {
    $("#same_billing_address_title").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: what is `#same_shipping_address_title`? and where is `shipping` class added to..which Jquery version ?

Comment: version 1.5.1 same+shipping_address_title is a select list and shipping is applied to inputs (the shipping part works, it copies input value to another input value but the select im having issues with

Comment: ..Please create a simple http://jsfiddle.net/ to explain the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuPkg/1/ - strange seems to work...... could be the other js i have so ill add that in

Comment: added other js but still works, just does not on my page.... would that be as its using jquery 1.5.2 and not 1.5.1 ?

Comment: P.S. I think you should not use .live() as it's depracted http://api.jquery.com/live/ use .on(), instead.

Comment: .on duid not seem to work so i left as live - it was uniform that was stopping it so i  had to update dom but works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to uniform which needed to `$.uniform.update()` to update the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to troubleshoot every step to see where it breaks down. Try this to start:

```
    $("#same_shipping_address_title").change(function () {
         console.log("change fired");
         var newvalue = $(this).val();
         console.log(newvalue);
         $("#same_billing_address_title").val(newvalue);
    });
```

then use the console in your browser's developer tools, and you should see confirmation of the fact that the change event was fired from #same_shipping_address_title, and its value.

Comment: works fine as doe sthe fiddle - do you think its uniform that is not allowing it to update the other?